# How to name flutter application, for example, `My App`?

Tags: flutter

How to create flutter application with the name, for example, `My App` (with space inside and with each word uppercased)?
If I create it this way

> flutter create my app

then the output is

> Multiple output directories specified.

On the other side if create it like

> flutter create my_app

then `my_app` will be the name of this app in the list of installed applications (at least on Android).

But how to name it `My App`?

A command line tool outputs this info:

> Package names should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate
>   words, `just_like_this`.  Use only basic Latin letters and Arabic
>   digits: [a-z0-9_]. Also, make sure the name is a valid Dart identifier
>   -- that it doesn't start with digits and isn't a reserved word.

So the lowercase is also required...

Comment: `flutter create "My App"` most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter documentation describe in detail how to configure your application for deployment which also includes setting the name of the app. You can find detailed configuration here -

- [Build and release an Android App](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest)
- [Build and release an iOS App](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings)

For changing the name of the Android app, it says -

> Review the default App Manifest file, AndroidManifest.xml, located in
>   /android/app/src/main and verify that the values are correct,
>   especially the following:
>
> application Edit the android:label in the application tag to reflect
>   the final name of the app.

For changing the name of the iOS app, it says -

> Navigate to your target’s settings in Xcode:
>
> In Xcode, open Runner.xcworkspace in your app’s ios folder. To view
>   your app’s settings, select the Runner project in the Xcode project
>   navigator. Then, in the main view sidebar, select the Runner target.
>   Select the General tab. Next, you’ll verify the most important
>   settings.
>
> In the Identity section:
>
> Display Name The name of the app to be displayed on the home screen
>   and elsewhere. Bundle Identifier